# How to resize a QGraphicsView after QGraphicsView::Scale

Tags: qt, resize, qgraphicsview

Is there non-hideous way to resize a QGraphicsView after a call of scale().

My QGraphicsView is embedded in a QScrollArea. When I zoom i want the View the get bigger.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` itself inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea`. Embedding it within another `QScrollArea` would be very strange, and is likely the source of your problems. By default, when you scale a `QGraphicsScene` larger than the `QGraphicsView` in which it is displayed, it will show the necessary scroll bars.

Comment: Ok, but with a small QGraphicsView, when i'm zooming, i want the view to grow. Now only the scrollbars appear and the view stays at its initial size

Comment: Oh, OK. Hmm ... you would have to subclass `QGraphicsView` and reimplement some functions. My guess would be `sizeHint` and probably also `resizeEvent` or `viewportEvent`. The sizeHint would be based on the scene's boundingRect. The layout into which it is embedded could then allow the view to have more space as needed.

Comment: BTW, is the view competing with other widgets on your window for space? Is there a reason you wouldn't want it to be as large as possible even if the scene it is rendering is smaller?

Comment: Its in a Gridlayout in a QFrame. I see nothing that could prevent the resize

Comment: I tried QGraphicsViewresize(scene->itemsBoundingRect() and nothing happens :/

Comment: Could it be a size policy problem ?

Comment: I found the problem : Part of the code was not mine. In the constructor i had a setMaximumHeight/Widget -_-